# byte to image C# from web app to windows app

Tags: c#, sql, windows

I have a web application that uploads images and stores them in SQL as image (column datatype image), and I have a windows application that reads from SQL DB as `datatable` and stores images in a folder.

The issue is when am trying to save the image it gives that format is not supported although I used `writeallbytes`.

[image]

```cs
byte[] ImagemByte = ObjectToByteArray(DtResult.Rows[0]["BackgroundImageByte"]);
string filename = "@" + Path.Combine(Conf.BgImagePath +
    "\\", DtResult.Rows[0]["ThemeId"].ToString() +
    DtResult.Rows[0]["BackgroundImage"].ToString());

byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

}
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, ImagemByte);
```

Comment: Fix the path: `string filename = Path.Combine(Conf.BgImagePath, $"{DtResult.Rows[0]["ThemeId"]}{DtResult.Rows[0]["BackgroundImage"]}");`, check what actually comes out of it (is it a server-mapped path?) and post what `ObjectToByteArray()` is doing. Possibly, don't use the `Image` storage format. Store just the bytes (if it's a new application, of course).

Comment: @Jimi
the return of the filename is a physical path, also i modified the question and added the ObjectToByteArray fucntion it tried to save without format its not recognized as image

Comment: Don't use ObjectToByteArray, if it's an Image use `myImg.Save("MY_PATH", ImageFormat.Bmp)` or just save the raw img bytes.

Comment: @Charles
i tried to save bytes but the format was not supported.

Comment: No BinaryFormatter, you have already an Image object type there. If you decide to/can store the Bitmaps as a byte array (using a `VARBINARY(MAX)` field), it's a storage format compatible with most databases. The `Image` format is ~deprecated.

Comment: Just a basic question, where are you getting this _format is not supported_ error. At `File.WriteAllBytes` or when you try to open the image that is created by the app?

Comment: @Thangadurai 
yes when am trying to open the image.

Comment: You don't need to use the ObjectToByteArray function, just cast the 'BackgroundImageByte' to array of bytes like `byte[] ImagemByte = (byte[])DtResult.Rows[0]["BackgroundImageByte"];`

Comment: @Thangadurai, it showed error casting
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64[]' to type 'System.Byte[]'
thats why i used the function

Comment: Please, post your database type and tag the question accordingly + Post and check the exact field types you're using + post the code that stores the Bitmap.

Comment: @Jimi i already mentioned that SQL datatype is image